# Vertical alignment of combining diacritic in graphviz

Tags: unicode, graphviz, dot

I have the following minimal dot code:

```
digraph {
    charset = utf8;
    rankdir = LR;
    "ε" -> "V" [label="V:V"];
    "ε" -> "ε" [label="C:C"];
    "V" -> "V" [label = "C:C"];
    "V" -> "ε" [label = "V:V́ "];
}
```

Note that the last `V` in the last line is followed by an acute combining diacritic (it is correctly combined with the `V` in my editor, FWIW). This diacritic does not appear high enough over the `V` after calling `dot -Tpdf foo.dot -o foo.pdf`. Instead, as you can see below, it is overlaid:

[image: Digraph with one V having a misaligned acute accent]

How do I fix this? I'm using dot version 2.38.0 on Ubuntu (xenial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works already.  If you look closely at your image, you will see the diacritic:

[image]

I think it's just the font that needs to be changed.  Referring to [Graphviz: change font for the whole graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879115/graphviz-change-font-for-the-whole-graph), I modified your dot code and added a font:

```
digraph {
    graph [fontname = "helvetica"];
    node [fontname = "helvetica"];
    edge [fontname = "helvetica"];

    charset = utf8;
    ...
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: The issue persists with Helvetica on my Linux machine. Why did you pick Helvetica (aka, what quality does Helvetica have on your machine that enables it to work)?

Comment: That's what was mentioned in the question.  You can run `fc-list` and try a different font name.  FWIW, I don't have an Ubuntu running but I tried on Mac and CentOS and it worked.